# Antd set a max limit of tags you can select from the Select component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the Select component from AntD in mode tags to create a tag input selector that would allow a user to select up to 5 random tags of their choosing.

```
const [optionsSelected, setOptionsSelected] = useState([]);

    const handleSelect = value => {
        console.log(value, optionsSelected);

        const options = optionsSelected.concat(value);
        setOptionsSelected(options.slice(0, 5));
    };

    return (
        <Form.Item
            name="keywords"
            label={<strong>Keywords</strong>}
            rules={[{required: true}]}
        >
            <Select
                mode="tags"
                maxTagTextLength={20}
                placeholder="e.g. JavaScript, Engineer, QA, Marketing, Customer Success, etc."
                notFoundContent={<div>Enter a keyword. Press enter to select it.</div>}
                onSelect={handleSelect}
                value={optionsSelected}
            />
        </Form.Item>
    );
```

However I cannot seem to get it to work so if the user tries to select more than 5 tags, then it wont allow them to.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: A simple length check would do, no? Also I don't see the purpose of the `.slice(0, 5)`.

Comment: yeah but where abouts do i do this check to prevent new tags from being added

Comment: Your `handleSelect` sounds like the place. Dont update your options unless if you have less than five tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by doing the following in handleSelect:

```
const handleSelect = () => {
        form.setFieldsValue({
            keywords: form.getFieldValue('keywords').slice(0, 5),
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track selected items count and disable unselected options when selected count is equal to max allowed count:

```js
function toRawValue(optionValue) {
  return typeof optionValue === "object" ? optionValue.value : optionValue;
}

export function MultiSelect({
  maxSelected,
  options: originalOptions,
  onChange: originalOnChange,
  ...selectProps
}) {
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState([]);

  // Proxy options to conditionally disable them
  const options = useMemo(() => {
    if (originalOptions === undefined) {
      return originalOptions;
    }

    const isMaxSelected = selectedValues.length === maxSelected;

    return originalOptions.map((option) => ({
      ...option,
      // Disable/enable unselected items to prevent/allow selection
      ...(!selectedValues.includes(option.value) && {
        disabled: isMaxSelected,
      }),
    }));
  }, [originalOptions, maxSelected, selectedValues]);

  const onChange = useCallback<OnChangeHandler>(
    (values, option) => {
      setSelectedValues(values.map(toRawValue));

      originalOnChange?.(values, option);
    },
    [originalOnChange],
  );

  return (
    <Select
      {...selectProps}
      options={options}
      mode="multiple"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
}
```

Related [issue on the repository](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/15244)